# Is surjectivity of a map in a long exact sequence equivalent to the following element being zero?

Tags: algebraic-topology, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

If one has a long exact sequence of $R$-modules
$$
\cdots \to A \to B \xrightarrow{f} C \to D \to \cdots
$$

and $f$ is known to be surjective, does this imply that $D\cong 0$ as $R$-modules? Or is this exact sequence is equivalent to one of the form
$$
\cdots \to A \to B \xrightarrow{f} C \to 0 \to \cdots
$$

I know the following is a theorem:

> The sequence $B\xrightarrow{f} C \to 0$ is exact $\iff f$ is an epimorphism.

But I suppose I don't know if this similar but slightly different statement is true:

> The sequence $B\xrightarrow{f} C \to D$ with $f$ an epimorphism is exact $\iff D \cong 0$.

(For context, I am using this in the Mayer-Vietoris sequence, where we've shown a map is surjective and would like to conclude that a certain later term must be zero.)

Comment: I'd also appreciate if anyone could comment on how to reconcile this with the apparent exactness of the sequence of $\Bbb{Z}$-modules given by $\cdots \xrightarrow{0} \Bbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\text{id}} \Bbb{Z} \xrightarrow{0} \Bbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\text{id}} \Bbb{Z} \to \cdots$, where the identity map is clearly surjective but none of the modules appearing are 0.

Comment: It seems that your comment answers your own question.

Comment: A map in a long exact sequence is surjective (or injective) if and only if the following (or preceding, respectively) map is the zero map. The codomain of the following map (or domain of the preceding map, respectively) does not have to be zero.

Comment: @EricWofsey Right, I suppose the comment is more about whether or not that serves as a valid counterexample, i.e. are the domains/codomains "really" $\Bbb{Z}$. or is what I've written the same as something like $\cdots \twoheadrightarrow 0 \hookrightarrow \Bbb{Z} \twoheadrightarrow 0 \hookrightarrow \Bbb{Z} \to \cdots$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang I see! So in my second statement, the converse implication is true, but not the forward implication? And it's not the case that there's something like a separate sequence $B' \to C' \xrightarrow{f} 0$ with maps $B\to B', C\to C', D\to 0$ yielding commuting squares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've given a perfectly good counterexample in the comments.  The sequence $$\cdots \xrightarrow{0} \Bbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\text{id}} \Bbb{Z} \xrightarrow{0} \Bbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\text{id}} \Bbb{Z} \to \cdots$$ is exact: the image of each map is the kernel of the next one.  The map $\mathrm{id}:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is surjective, but the object following it in the sequence is another $\mathbb{Z}$, not $0$.

In general, if you have a sequence $B\stackrel{f}\to C\to D$, exactness just says that the image of $f$ is equal to the kernel of the map $C\to D$.  So, $f$ is surjective iff the map $C\to D$ is $0$ (so that its kernel is all of $C$).  But this doesn't mean $D$ itself has to be $0$, since you can have a zero homomorphism to any module at all.  If the sequence continues with a map $D\to E$, then exactness at $D$ would additionally tell you the map $D\to E$ must be injective (its kernel must be the image of the map $C\to D$, which we know is $0$).